# Displaying Price of packages from an effective date in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to draft revenue on a graph and prices for packages changed last month.
How can I update the prices for the packages.

```
     SELECT   TO_DATE(DATEADD(hh, -7, JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT(PROPERTY_HS_DATE_ENTERED_904938, 'value' ))) AS WIN_DATE_PST,
TO_VARCHAR(JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT(PROPERTY_PRODUCT_PURCHASED , 'value' )) AS PRODUCT_PURCHASED,
    
    
 

    case when close_date_pst < 'Sep 2 2021' then
            case 
                when PRODUCT_PURCHASED = 'Academy - Admissions' then 2997
                when PRODUCT_PURCHASED = 'Academy - Regular' then 1497
                when PRODUCT_PURCHASED = 'Support Monthly' then 152.52
                when PRODUCT_PURCHASED = 'Information Monthly' then 152.52
                when PRODUCT_PURCHASED = 'Academy - Monthly' then 152.52
                when PRODUCT_PURCHASED = 'Consulting Monthly' then 152.52
                else
                  case 
                   when PRODUCT_PURCHASED = 'Academy - Admissions' then 3146.85
                   when PRODUCT_PURCHASED = 'Academy - Regular' then 2096.85
                   when PRODUCT_PURCHASED = 'Support Monthly' then 160.15
                   when PRODUCT_PURCHASED = 'Information Monthly' then 160.15
                   when PRODUCT_PURCHASED = 'Academy - Monthly' then 160.15
                   when PRODUCT_PURCHASED = 'Consulting Monthly' then 160.15
            end as REVENUE
        FROM XYZ
```

I believe I am not putting the date filter in right format. This code doesn't work for me.

Comment: I can't see an `UPDATE` statement anywhere in your code. All you have is a `SELECT`.

Comment: He @HanletEscaño Thanks. But I am just trying to view the table and not update the raw data. 
In raw data there is not price for these packages mentioned. I used CASE WHEN to view the prices.

Comment: Ok, it is just that your title and question made me think that you just want to update the table. It is not very clear what you need. I think there is an issue with your first case (you dont close it)

Comment: @HanletEscaño Thanks I just ended all three cases. I got a new error that my date is not recognized. Its a progress here. Thanks again.

Comment: Yeah you have to work with whatever date type you got. Not sure if 'Sep 2 2021' is a valid date. Try using something like '2021-09-02' and good luck.

Comment: @HanletEscaño Awesome. The date format you mentioned worked. Query ran. 
But now any field after that date is displaying price as 0. I am trying to figure that out now.